# External Profiler for Unity 3D apps

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, profiling, profile, profiler

Hello is there a way to profile a Process with an external profiler? I use the unity profiler but it dosent show me allocations in other threads then the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that use Unity Profiler is the best way to profile Unity authored apps/games. Unity Profiler shows allocations only on the main thread, because is there where your game code resides.

In some cases we can create our own threads to do some calculations, I imagine is this your case, so I recommend to you use [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler) and [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), I used both of them to profile ordinary .NET apps and they are really amazing profiles and, yes, they show allocations to all your app's threads.

Comment: It looks like ANTS does not work with Unity because it is not a .net app (at least the editor)